# Would it be possible if someone knew Legilimency and was on the Quidditch Team, to cheat because you could read the opponents minds?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch, legilimens

If I was writing a fanfic, and my own character knew Legilimency and Occlumency and the teachers knew, would they say anything to her? Also, my character doesn't require a wand to use Legilimency. Like, not to cheat using Legilimency? Would it even be feasible or possible to cheat using Legilimency to peer into your Opponents minds to see what they were going to do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, while we have you please take the [tour] and checkout the [help]. I am seeing 3-4 questions here that should be split up, though not all are definitely answerable... "1. Would they (teachers) say anything? 2. Does Legilimency require a wand? 3. Would it be feasible to use Legilimency while flying a broom? 4. Will Legilimency show my character what their opponent will do next". We can only answer one at a time, so you will likely get better results by asking multiple questions, even if they're closely related.

Comment: If you only want to know if it's possible, then you'd still be better off focusing this question on that premise, and let the answerer address the relevant parts

Answer (score 5):

I believe using Legilimency in Quidditch against the opposing team would count as cheating per rule 6:

> 6. Wands may be taken on to the pitch [NOTE: The right to carry a wand at all times was established by the International Confederation of Wizards in 1692, when Muggle persecution was at its height and the wizards were planning their retreat into hiding.] but must under no circumstances whatsoever be used against opposing team members, any opposing team member’s broom, the referee, any of the balls, or any member of the crowd.
>
> <sub>*Quidditch Through the Ages*, "Rules"</sub>

The rule is of course talking about using wands on opponents but I think we can open that up more and that the rule is designed to not use any kind of magic against an opponent. Using Legilimency against an opponent really seems to fall foul of this rule.

On top of that, whilst not necessary, eye contact helps make Legilimency easier. That's hard to do whilst flying a broom, never mind then also in the middle of a game of Quidditch.

> "The Dark Lord is at a considerable distance and the walls and grounds of Hogwarts are guarded by many ancient spells and charms to ensure the bodily and mental safety of those who dwell within them," said Snape. "Time and space matter in magic, Potter. Eye contact is often essential to Legilimency."
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter 24, "Occlumency"</sub>

I think we also have to challenge the premise of the question here as well. Legilimency is already quite a skilled piece of magic not really available to students. On top of that you're saying this student can do this wandlessly *and* most likely non-verbally. That means they would be one of the most skilled Legilimens there is and they are still a student? Wandless magic is already considered advanced for a student, this is something else. And you think they can do it whilst playing Quidditch which would be taking up a lot of their mental capacity. This student sounds like one of the most skilled Witches there is and they're still only a student.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, a wizard generally needed eye contact to perform Legilimency. I doubt any character would be making a lot of eye contact with the opposing team during a quidditch match to even have the opportunity.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to include some evidence that this is the case? A good answer should include evidence (quotes in this case) to back it up. However, I believe eye contact only makes it easier and if someone is proficient enough to do it wandlessly then they don't really need eye contact. However, that begs the question of if a young Witch/Wizard would be proficient enough in the first place to do it wandlessly and if they could do it whilst also playing Quidditch.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it even be feasible or possible to cheat using Legilimency to peer into your Opponents minds to see what they were going to do?

It's unlikely. Even if you could successfully use Legilimency on an opponent in the middle of a Quidditch match (and other answers have covered why that would be difficult, if not outright impossible), as Snape explains to Harry, Legilimency is not mind reading.

> "It is the ability to extract feelings and memories from another person's mind -"
> "He can read minds?" said Harry quickly, his worst fears confirmed.
> ...
> "Only Muggles talk of 'mind reading.' The mind is not a book, to be opened at will and examined at leisure. Thoughts are not etched on the inside of skulls, to be perused by any invader. ..."
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter Twenty-Four - Occlumency</sub>

Feelings and memories generally wouldn't be useful in telling you what your opponent is going to do. They obviously have no memory of what they haven't yet done, and e.g. "I'm going to pass to the player on my left" is not what would generally be considered a feeling.

However, it's possible that in situations where the opposing team is using a specific, practiced strategy you'd be able to view the relevant memories from training sessions, and therefore know what will happen next. Even then, you probably wouldn't get useful information quickly enough to make use of it before the situation has changed.